# while bootstrapping a recipe on windows machine ..facing issues like Network error

Tags: knife, chef-infra

Bootstrapping Chef on windows

****ERROR: Network Error: Connection refused - connect(2)**

**Check your knife configuration and network settings****

I have installed knife windows pluggin and also configured the winrm but after doing this also .. i am facing this issue .

I could not resolve this. Has anyone come across this problem and found a solution?

Comment: Does winrs see the same problem?

winrs -r:http://machinename:5985 "ver"

You can find out the port by running this command on the target machine

"winrm enumerate winrm/config/listener"

You can supply a username password with the original command to check access. It does sound like either firewall or unknown account to me but I've only used this feature briefly

Comment: yah.. thanks patrick issue solved. Error solved after activating  5986 port .